# include pdf in latex (appendix)

Tags: pdfpages

I am facing a big problem I am adding many Pdf files using includepdf in appendix, the problem is that when I start numbering my pages in appendix, I start having my fancyhead which I don't want it to appear 
My code is :

```
\documentclass[oneside,fr,maths]{ty_book}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\input{title}   
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{fancy}
\geometry{top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=0.8in}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{ESSA}}
\fancyfoot[C]{-- \thepage\ / \pageref*{LastPage} --}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{ESSA}}
\fancyfoot[C]{-- \thepage\ / \pageref*{LastPage} --}}


\begin{appendices}
\newpage
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering 
\includepdf[pages=1,\includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{DMOS1}
\end{figure}
\newpage
\end{document}
```

To do brief I want to include a pdf file by numbering my pages without having a fancyhead

Comment: (1) you cannot use `\includepdf` inside a figure, the included image is larger than what is allowed for a figure. (2) `\includepdf[...,\includepdf[[....]` makes not sense at all.

Comment: I have delete the begin figure. So How can I add a numbering for my pages without adding my fancyhead

Comment: `\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{DMOS1}` should do it.

Comment: I have already tried this syntax it add's a numbering plus fancyhead...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting code fragments it is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A LaTeX MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem -- so you should include your fancy header code. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Comment: I have updated my code

Comment: @Abdallah full minimal example, something we can copy and test without having to add anything (other than perhaps the included PDF), here there is no documentclass, no document env etc

Comment: Plus your code clearly shows that you have overwritten `plain`, a style that normally only shows a page number, so of course you get number plus header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MWE is not given. Still find this solution using memoir

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}


\begin{document}


\backmatter

\includepdf[pages=1-2,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{Sample}
\newpage

\end{document}
```

This is working for me.  Please ensure a pdf file named Sample.pdf is in its folder.